# Efficiently convert random bytes to string without much loss of entropy

Tags: c, string, random, cryptography, byte

I need a cryptographically random string to serve as the session identifier in my Web app. Here is my current implementation with [`libsodium`](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium):

```
char session_id[81];
sprintf(session_id, "%"
        PRIx32
        "%"
        PRIx32
        "%"
        PRIx32
        "%"
        PRIx32
        "%"
        PRIx32
        "%"
        PRIx32
        "%"
        PRIx32
        "%"
        PRIx32,
        randombytes_random(), randombytes_random(), randombytes_random(), randombytes_random(),
        randombytes_random(), randombytes_random(), randombytes_random(), randombytes_random());
```

An example resulting string looks like:

> 36b95095192b4b3999804c95605aee06bd3381e4197cdfa5230a37425a863d40

I think this is the most obvious way. This problem is that most of the key space is unused: there are 36 alphanumeric characters even if we ignore case sensitivity, but only 16 of which (`0-9`, `A-E`, and a latent `X` from the `0X` prefix) would appear in the resulting string. How can I improve the current approach by making use of more of the key space?

The convert should be as efficient as possible, but on the other hand I hope most of the randomness is preserved. Please note that I don't expect ALL entropy to be preserved if that operation would be too expansive. Instead, I'm seeking a balance between the length of the resulting string, performance, and the amount of entropy.

I'm already using `libsodium` for other functionalities in my project, and I'd like to stick to it. Please avoid suggesting another library unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: what are the desired constrained for the string ? to be printable ? have you considered [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: @dvhh There are no requirements besides it have to be stored in an HTTP cookie, and base64 looks like a valid option! You can make it an answer and I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: Are you sure you limit the key space? The key is 32bytes represented as 64 hex digits. Using Base64 encoding you might get down to 43 characters but the randomness of your key is not affected at all. It's still the very same 256 bits that you are encoding.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes I understand that, and there could be some wording issues in my question. What I wanted to say is, by making use of more alphanumeric characters, I can get the same randomness with a shorter string to pass over the network and store in the client, which is desirable.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment and event considering your constraints ( being stored in a HTTP cookie ) it seem that [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best encoding from a size perspective, better even than base64, is [Base85 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85).